# WPF ComboBox with entity framework orderBy

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I filled the ComboBox in my Project like this

```
            CB_City.ItemsSource = c.Cities;
            CB_City.DisplayMemberPath = "city1";
            CB_City.SelectedValuePath = "city_id";
            CB_City.SelectedValue = 517;
```

I work with entity Framework and c# ,
How can I sort the results in order by ascending?

Still can not (I'm trying a lot) I am attaching the full code

```
           using (MorEntities1  c = new MorEntities1())
        {
            CB_City.ItemsSource = c.Cities;
            CB_City.DisplayMemberPath = "city1";
            CB_City.SelectedValuePath = "city_id";
            CB_City.SelectedValue = 517;
        }
```

Comment: Why you can't just do `c.Cities.OrderBy(c => c.Name)` or something like that?

Comment: I do not know why, but it does not work. I am working on WPF, sorry I forgot to write

Comment: What is c.Cities? Give us a type declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to the post by @Ross, you can also get the `CollectionViewSource` this way:

```
var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(CB_City.ItemsSource);
view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("city1", 
    ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works great, sorry for the delay thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use: `CB_City.ItemsSource = c.Cities.OrderBy(c=>c.Text)` or `CB_City.ItemsSource = c.Cities.OrderBy(c=>c.Text)`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a `CollectionViewSource` with a `SortDescription`:

```
var myViewSource = new CollectionViewSource { Source = c.Cities.ToList() };
myViewSource.SortDescriptions.Add(
  new SortDescription("YOUR_PROPERTY", ListSortDirection.Ascending)
);
CB_City.ItemsSource = myViewSource.View;
```

Comment: +1. I would go the `CollectionViewSource` any day, over the sorting of `ItemsSource`.